# Changing Date formats in Target Tables in informatica

Tags: database, oracle, informatica

In informatica i receive dates from flat files in the format of dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy i need to convert all date to one format i.e dd-mm-yyyy using any expression and push into target ,so no rows gets rejected.how to proceed with them?

Comment: been a while since I've used Informatica, but you can write your own conversions either using built-in string functions or even as java.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling data as "date" data type, you should have no problems with respect to rejections.

About handling a particular date format string, you can look at the properties at the integration service level, there you can control the date format (default).